# Swing JTable does not show anything

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I added Jtable to my JPanel, *it is simple code* but screen shows nothing. Help Help Help Help Help Help Help Help .Here is my code:

```
public class AddProduct extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    Connection con;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AddProduct frame = new AddProduct();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public AddProduct() {

        con = MySQLConnection.getConnection();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 832, 466);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        String[] column_headers = {"Team", "Pointers", "Goal Diff"};
        String[][] team_statics = {{"Man Utd", "65", "40"}, {"Chelsea", "63", "38"}};

        table = new JTable();
        table.setBounds(0, 297, 501, -296);
        contentPane.add(table);
  }
}
```

I am exactly doing what I watch in video.

Comment: stop watching (only) videos, read tutorials (e.g. using `null` Layout is mostly not good; extending a `JFrame` is not good; I never had to set the content pane; ...) A good starting address: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing: Table of Contents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)

Comment: Why table is empty? There is no data to display: `column_headers` and `team_statistics` are declared/initialized but **never used** anywhere. Probably they are meant to be used as arguments in the constructor of the table `table = new JTable(team_statistics, column_headers);` Also hard to believe the table should have negative height `-296` ! (videos/images are good for showing GUI/menus/... but not the best to *read* code)

Comment: Thank you all I found my mistake. Problem was height.